# Spacing around subsections in amsart

Tags: spacing, amsart

Is there a way to adjust a spacing for subsections?
I am working with the document class amsart and I
want to add the same spacing around each new subsection.
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Please clarify what you mean by "I want to add the same spacing around each new subsection". Same spacing as what? By default, the `amsart` document class typesets subsection-level headers flush-left and in run-in style, so that there's no line break before the  following text starts. LaTeX is also set to insert a bit of whitespace *above*  subsection-level headers. What about these default settings do you wish to change?

Comment: @Mico.That was exactly what I was thinking about. I want to change the default settings in the beginning, so that each subsection has the same spacing. By this, I mean that before or after Lemmas, Definitions, etc or just a text element the spacing  of the subsections remain the same. I hope, it is clear now, what I actually mean ...